# (python) write multiple tuple to string with indent

Tags: python-3.x, string, tuples

I have a tuple of characters like such:

```
('a', ':', '4')('b', ':', '3')('c', ':', '4')('d', ':', '7')
```

How do I convert it to a string so that it is like:

```
a:4
b:3
c:4
d:7
```

I tried below but it doesn't success.
"text" is the one has multiple tuples

```
    for key in dict:
        if dict[key] >= 2:
            text = key, ":", dict[key]
            f.writelines(','.join(map(str, text)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed to below and solved.

```
for key in dict:
    if dict[key] >= 2:
        text = '{}{}{}{}'.format(key, ":", dict[key],'\n')
        f.write(text)
```